# "There will be a translated clip tomorrow." equivalent to "There will be a clip that is/was/has been/will have been translated tomorrow."?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

Can I reduce a relative clause like down below?

For example:

Right now, there is no translated clip.

I say,

> "There will be a translated clip tomorrow."

Can it be equivalent to

> "There will be a clip that is/was/has been/will have been translated tomorrow."

By the way, which one is correct? is or was or has been or will have been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'There will be a translated clip tomorrow.'

The above is fine.

It is equivalent to

"There will be a clip that will have been translated tomorrow."